# dockers for windows - SQL Server Agent missing

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm pulling down the latest image but SQL agent does not show up in SQL management Studio even though I'm including MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=True.  Any ideas?  Dockers for Windows Engine 19.03.13

```
docker run `
 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" `
 -e "SA_PASSWORD=***********" `
 -e "MSSQL_AGENT_ENABLED=True" `
 -p 1433:1433 `
 --name sql1 `
 -v sql1_volume:/var/opt/mssql `
 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Comment: I assume you aren't using Express?

Comment: @larnu - Developer Edition